# How to send part of form data using JQuery & Ajax to php without submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an application for rating a service. A on the form page has inputs for comment, giving it a star etc.
I want to make it in a way that when a user clicks on a star it should send the value of the star input to a php script for processing without having to click on the submit button. I thought of using separate forms for this, however, i just want to use one form because different forms will bring the layout.
HTML Form

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <textarea name="comment"></textarea>

   <input type="radio" name="rate" value="1">
   <input type="radio" name="rate" value="2">
   
   <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JQuery for the sending rate to php

```
 $("input[name=rate]").change(function(event){

   var rating_num = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
     url: '../handlers/rating.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: rating_num,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
    beforeSend:function(){
                    
    },
    success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
    }
  }); 

})
```

rating.php

```
echo $_POST['rating_num'];
```

The output I get is "undefined index:rating_num"

The above code is just a sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can debug your `$_POST` variable with `var_dump` function.

However, the reason why you have this error is that you need to put an object in the 'data' parameter.

```
{
  ...
  data: {
    rating_num: rating_num
  },
  ...
}
```

Also, you could use $.post instead of $.ajax. See examples in [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

```
$.post('rating.php', {rating_num: rating_num})
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: It worked. The $. Post Recommendation did it for me